# Python run process as .exe with out opening any console windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pyinstaller, keylogger

Recently, I tried making a new Key logger and I used this piece of code to run it as background process:

```
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008

pid = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "KeyLogger.py"],
                       creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS).pid
```

My code works properly when I run this as a python file, but when I convert it to a .exe file using :

```
pyinstaller --onefile myfile.py
```

it doesn't work any more.
But when I remove this piece of code :

```
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008

    pid = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "KeyLogger.py"],
                           creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS).pid
```

it works fine.
Now, I'm looking for a new way to run my python code as a background process (as .exe) without showing any console windows.
**In addition, I'm sorry for writing mistakes in my question.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, python files have the extension .py . If you want to run your program without opening a console window, change the extension to .pyw. 
To convert a .py file to a .exe file (with PyInstaller) which will not open the console, use one of the following commands (see [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/usage.html) for more info):

`pyinstaller -w yourfile.py`

`pyinstaller --windowed yourfile.py`

`pyinstaller --noconsole yourfile.py`

Comment: I convert .py to .exe then I run it. I want that my .exe file run without any opening console window not my .py and when I use subprocess lib, it automatically run it without showing any window but it doesn't work when I convert it to .exe

Comment: thanks, I use this command and it work properly :
`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole KeyLogger.py`